# File path textbox in the image uploaded is too wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images

After the latest edits in CSS/HTML of (Meta) Stack Overflow the `<input type="file"...>` is too wide. See the screenshot:

> [image]

I use Firefox 18.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It's a feature allowing you to upload bigger images than before. ;)

Comment: @Bart Yeah, sure. And another feature: you see more from the file path. ;-)

Comment: On Mac os / Firefox 20, it feet aptly: http://cl.ly/image/2h1S2M3h2n0e

Comment: This has been optimized for Opera: [perfectly aligned](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MV9WO.png). :P

Comment: This isn't "right" on FF 19 on Windows either - it's too narrow! I believe this is a long-standing bug in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shog9 [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169940/file-path-textbox-in-the-image-uploaded-is-too-wide#comment502266_169940), this is basically a bug in Firefox - it will not respect width styles on file inputs.

I have added a size attribute on the file input so it *shouldn't* go over the dialog width, but YMMV (the Windows and Linux versions of FF do different things here). There is also the issue of what fonts and font sizes you are using etc...

Tested on Linux Mint, FF 19 and will be there on the next build.